# How do I stop this from appearing when I boot up my laptop? (screenshot)

Tags: boot, software-installation, flash

[image: Failure to dowload extra files]
It appears everytime I boot up my laptop and I always click "run this action now" but nothing changes

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Jobin No I am not

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` and reboot to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @Jobin Sorry for the slow response...I have done that but the problem still persists

Answer (score 2):

First ensure that you have an active internet connection and  open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Then try to reboot to see if flash is properly installed this time.

Comment: I tried this but it still appears

Answer (score 2):

Try to clean and remove all the unused packages.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: I tried this but it still appears